# Is is legal/right to watch anime/read manga online?

Tags: discussion

You can find virtually all major manga/anime online at a lot of random sites, but is it right to support these sites.

I thought the reason YouTube stopped allowing these to be shown was because of copyright violations.

Comment: We aren't here to make moral decisions for you. It's true that if you're watching anime through an unlicensed source, it probably violates copyright law. The ethics could be debated a great deal, but neither meta nor the main site is the place for that debate.

Comment: After some very lengthy discussions, we've agreed to **professionally not care** about copyrighted material ***if*** it complements the post it is on. Adding a manga panel or two to aid with the answer is cool. Answering a question asking about where to watch anime online is not.